# IO Exception with enemy graphics

Tags: java, ioexception

I am working on a side scrolling shooter and when trying to upload the image for my ship graphic, It either says unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown, or it will say Illegal start of expression and Interface, class, or enum expected for many of my lines of code.

class ship1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

```
Image image = null;


    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("ship1.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
int x = 800, y = 250;
double xVel = -2, yVel = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    t.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    x += (int) xVel;
    yVel = 5 * Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(x) / 750);
    y += (int) yVel;
    repaint();
}
```

}

Comment: You can't put a `try`/`catch` block like that just in a class declaration - it has to be in a constructor or method.

Comment: Starting a Timer inside a painting method is a very bad idea.  You don’t know when paintComponent will be called.  It can be called, for example, when the window is moved, when a screen saver kicks in, or even when the user moves the mouse pointer over the window.  It’s not uncommon for a painting method to be called several times per second.

Comment: Thanks for the help.